# Wordpress: Jquery error while editing post or page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post

I'm using wordpress, lately I'm having a jquery error while editing a page or a post, saying that `jQuery is not defined`. I don't know how this happened.

did anyone have the same issue? Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?  The error *seems* to be jQuery not being included correctly, but there are other causes for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I compared my local files with the one on the server and found out that the file on wp-admin\js\editor.js is empty!
I updated it and it worked!